# When I catch the Exception and log it, the log just displays The Exception Name, not the Exception Stack

Tags: java, exception, log4j, error-logging

Though the log in server, the log display the Exception Name : NullPointerException, but the Exception Stack not display so that I could't find the source of the error.

Please tell me why the log did't display the Exception stack, and how could I right it ? And the log system is log4j system

```
try {
   // ... function called
} catch (Throwable t) {
   log.error("the Exception is : ", t);
}
```

The error log just displays : the Exception is : java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Use `logger.catching(t)` or add `t.getStackTrace()` as parameter.

If you use `logger.error(<A String>, <A Object>)` log4j will simply use the `toString` method of the Object.

Comment: That's not what [this javadoc](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Logger.html) says.  Or are you looking at a different class?

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of log4j2. Do you have checked in the debugger if the StackTrace is set? Have you been throwing this exception manually?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Log4j? If yes, you are using the correct two parameter method actually. It should print the stack trace as well. Refer docs for error- http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/index.html

If you still want the stack trace otherwise try this.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
ex.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(sw));
String stacktrace = sw.toString();
log.error(stacktrace);
```

But I would advise you to stick to your implementation.